# R simulation of casino

Tags: r

Im trying to do a code where there parameters are p=probability to win and kapital=money I play wtih. Each time I play and win I earn 1 dollar, if I loose I will loose 1 dollar.

When I reach 5 dollars i want to return(1) and when I reach 0 dollars I want to return (0). The function one_play is an already existing function that works.

```
casino_play <- function(p, capital){
while(capital<5 && capital>0){
 previous_capital <- one_play(p,capital)
 capital <- previous_capital
  
  if(previous_capital==0){
  return(0)}
  else if(previous_capital==5){
  return(1) 
 }
 }
}
```

My code does not work and I'm wondering if someone could possibly help me out?

Comment: Get rid of the `repeat` loop, why should it ever return something if the value of `previous_capital` doesn't change?

Comment: I want the loop to continue until previous_capital reach 0 or 5 was my though

Comment: But there's no need for `repeat`. The problem with the code is that you are complicating what is already solved by the *other* loop. Remove the inner loop and give it a try.

Comment: Be consistent with `capital` and `kapital`. Other than that I think this just needs a line `capital <- previous_capital` at the end of the `while` loop now.

Comment: i changed it now, did place it right?

Comment: I'd tidy it up a bit, but it looks like it would work to me. Doesn't it?